# Batch file to send a file to an FTP server

Tags: scripting, ftp, batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2003

I have a batch file (ftp.bat) that looks like:

```
@echo off
echo user etm124> ftpcmd.dat
echo testing123>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.DriveHQ.com
del ftpcmd.dat
```

This file is located in `C:\`. Also located in that directory is a file called `remote.txt`. When running this in the `C:\` directory, it just hangs:

`C:\>ftp.bat c:\remote.txt`

If I look in the `C:\`, I can see that the `ftpcmd.dat` file has been created, but my script just hangs.

**When I run this locally on my machine, I can send files just fine. But if I try to run this on one of my Windows Server 2003 machines, it hangs.**

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the script will trigger an infinite loop, which causes the script to never stop. Try omitting the *@echo off* from your script to see this happening. Either try renaming your batch file, add an extension to the ftp command (ftp.exe) or even provide a full path to the executable to make it work.